# Is there a "parent" function for the JavaScript factory pattern?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting to know the JavaScript factory pattern.

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/959L1xhe

I have one class `Customer` that inherits another `Person` and in the `display()` method in Customer I want to add to what the method does in Person.

**Is there a `parent`-like command to do this, or is the best way to do it the way below, which is a bit of a hack?**

```
function Customer(firstName, lastName, company) {
    var person = Person(firstName, lastName);
    var personDisplayHtml = person.display();
    person.display = function() {
        //return person.display() + ' ('+ company+')';  //error: too much recursion
        return personDisplayHtml + ' ('+ company+')';  
    }
    return person;
}
```

Comment: why not using prototypes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are of course an infinitude of variations on the situation you're talking about, but in your simple case you could construct the overriding "display" function by wrapping code around the original value:

```
function Customer(firstName, lastName, company) {
    var person = Person(firstName, lastName);
    person.display = function(display) {
        return function() {
            return display.call(person) + ' ('+ company+')';
        };
    }(person.display);
    return person;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2t5j75xy/

Answer (score 2):

I would change your code with

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    return {
        display : function() {
            return lastName + ', ' + firstName;
        }
    }
}

function Customer(person, company) {
    return {
        display: function() {
            return person.display() + ' (' + company + ')';
        }
    }
}

angular.module('app', [])
.controller('CalculatorController', function($scope) {

    $scope.persons = [];
    $scope.persons.push(Person('Jim', 'Thompson'));
    $scope.persons.push(Person('Jack', 'Harrison'));
    $scope.persons.push(Customer(Person('Mandy', 'Baker'), 'Acme Inc.'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/959L1xhe/1/

Answer (score 1):

I would use prototypes, because they are there for what you are asking...
like this ([updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/959L1xhe/3/)):

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.lastName=lastName;
}

Person.prototype={
    display : function() {
            return this.lastName + ', ' + this.firstName;
        },
    constructor:Person
};

function Customer(firstName, lastName, company) {
    Person.call(this,firstName,lastName);
    this.company=company;
}

Customer.prototype=new Person();

Customer.prototype.display=function(){
    return Person.prototype.display.call(this)+' ('+ this.company+')';
}

Customer.prototype.constructor=Customer;

angular.module('app', [])
.controller('CalculatorController', function($scope) {

    $scope.persons = [];
    $scope.persons.push(new Person('Jim', 'Thompson'));
    $scope.persons.push(new Person('Jack', 'Harrison'));
    $scope.persons.push(new Customer('Mandy', 'Baker', 'Acme Inc.'));
});
```

the advantage is that if you do something like this:

```
var cust=new Customer("test","test","test");
console.log(cust instanceof Person);
```

`cust instanceof Person` returns `true` whereas with your code construction, it will return false.